# droid cam makefile understanding and error

Tags: linux, fedora

I tried installing the droid cam on my fedora 19 (64 bit) .

Link to the droid cam application is [here](http://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/)

and whenever I try to install it , the Makefile which is as follows is invoked

```
obj-m := v4l2loopback-dc.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`

test:
        gcc test.c -o test

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` clean

insmod:
        sudo insmod v4l2loopback-dc.ko width=320 height=240

rmmod:
        sudo rmmod v4l2loopback-dc.ko
```

and here is the error

```
 -- INSTALL:  Webcam parameters: '320' and '240'
 -- INSTALL:  Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make: *** /lib/modules/3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
 -- INSTALL:  v4l2loopback-dc.ko not built.. Failure
```

build happens to be a symbolic link.I was wondering what exactly is the makefile trying to and why is it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build is trying to find the kernel headers. Install `kernel-devel-3.9.5-301.fc19.x86_64`.

Comment: out of curiosity , and just for future reference, how did you know it's looking for kernel headers?

Comment: @nerorevenge: Experience. Also, the symlink points somewhere (which was not available on your system at that time), and yum can tell you which package contains what it points to.

Comment: apologies about the wait, just needed to verify.